# NoSuchMethodException when sending jms communicate via ibm mq

Tags: java, spring, jboss, websphere, ibm-mq

I have Java app with Spring deployed on Jboss EAP 7 I am trying to communicate with IBM MQ thus I deployed on Jboss resource adapter wmq.jmsra.rar of version 9.0.0.1 and to my java project I've added given dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.connector</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I made sure that these versions are identical of allclient and resource adapter.
I've extracted required allclient jar and resource adapter from downloaded 9.0.0.10-IBM-MQ-Install-Java-All from ibm site.

When trying to send message I'm getting following exception:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
jboss_1  | The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
jboss_1  | See the linked exception for further information.
jboss_1  |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
jboss_1  |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
jboss_1  |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
jboss_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:172)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7809)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:350)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:131)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:134)
jboss_1  |  ... 63 more
jboss_1  | Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException[com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment, int)],3=Class.getConstructor0]
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:793)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:638)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:164)
jboss_1  |  ... 68 more
jboss_1  | Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.<init>(com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment, int)
jboss_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
jboss_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
jboss_1  |  at deployment.wmq.jmsra.rar//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:700)
jboss_1  |  ... 70 more
```

I've made sure that resource adapter has this particular method. What else can I check?

Comment: com.ibm.mq.jmqi is a different package than the two dependencies you added.

Comment: But com.ibm.mq.allclient already includes that package

Comment: did you try reimport maven project or mvn clean verify in command line?

Comment: mvn verify results with success

Comment: added my comment as an answer

Comment: If you use the RA you don't need the allclient.  Try removing `com.ibm.allclient jar`.

Comment: After removing it I'm getting 
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ibm/mq/connector/outbound/ConnectionFactoryImpl (Module "deployment.test.war" from Service Module Loader): com/ibm/msg/client/commonservices/trace/DumpableObject`

Comment: Should I also get rid of connector?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have 2 versions of the same class one having this method and the other doesn't hence its failing at runtime as it is picking up the wrong version of the class.

To sort this out, you can change class loading to verbose in jboss.

1. cd <JBOSS_HOME>\bin\ directory.
2. Open $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf
3. (bat or sh file) in a text editor and locate the lines where
   JAVA_OPTS is set (there are several of them), add -verbose:class to
   any of them.  Example (Windows) set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%
   ​-XX:+TraceClassLoading -verbose:class"​
4. Save the file. Restart the JBoss application.
5. Now you search for this class in the server logs. See if there are multiple entries and find the jar containing the same.
6. Identify the one you need and remove the other one.

Comment: What I've noticed after that this class is not loaded from resource adapter even though it's there.

Comment: ohkee but, did you find another version of this class ??

Comment: There is just one version the one from maven